# How do I insert CData value into azure table storage row

Tags: windows, azure, cdata

I just can't insert a CData value into table row.

my new table entity  is like

```
new Book { Description = new XCData("Asp.net<What>XXXXX</What>").ToString(), CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, })
```

and then I insert the book via context.

THe result:

```
<Properties><CreatedOn>2010-02-18T10:17:10.953Z</CreatedOn><Name>&lt;![CDATA[Asp.net&lt;What&gt;XXXXX&lt;/What&gt;]]&gt;</Name></Properties>
```

What I want is:

```
<Properties><CreatedOn>2010-02-18T10:17:10.953Z</CreatedOn><Name><![CDATA[Asp.net<What>XXXXX</What>]]></Name></Properties>
```

How do I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such usage isn't part of the *happy way* with the StorageClient 1.1 library; but you can use [DataServiceContext.WritingEntities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.writingentity%28VS.100%29.aspx) to achieve this behavior (although, it's rather a hacky approach).